# CSS Files Opening Up as Plain Text in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason, whenever I create a new file and give it a css extension, the language mode is set to plain text.  That is not the usual behavior and I don't know why it is acting that way.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- Click to the language at the right bottom bar of VSCode
  [image]
- Select `Configure File Association for '.css'` [image]
- Find `CSS` and select it.

---

You could run into problem cannot finding `CSS` in the last step I mentioned above, then here might be the fix for it btw:

- Press `Ctrl` + `,` to open the Settings window.
- Click `Open Settings (JSON)`[image]
- Find a line where there is

```
  "files.associations": {
       "*.css": "Plain Text"
   }
```

and delete it, make sure the json file still in a correct format after deleting (no missing or extra comma `,`).